# Streetview API not returning streetview

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page which should contain a div with a google map and a div with streetview. The map works fine, however the streetview doesnt show at all, its just an empty div. But I cant get the JS to throw an error.

here is my code, its probably something really obvious im missing.

```
<div id="property_streetview"></div>
                <script>


                    function initialize_StreetMap() {
                        var streetViewLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(52.39648,-4.071235);
                        var panoramaOptions = {
                            addressControl: false,
                            navigationControl: true,
                            navigationControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                            }
                        };
                        var panorama;
                        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("property_streetview"), panoramaOptions);

                    }

                    window.onload = initialize_StreetMap();


                </script>
```

Comment: First thing I noticed: you have panorama defined twice.  You only need the second one (i.e. the one where you assign new google.maps...etc. to it).  I don't know if this would be enough to break your view (unless you're doing a build with JS linting on or something like that), but it's worth removing the first instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a variable for a LatLng(`streetViewLocation` ), but when you want to get a streetview for that location you must use this variable as `position`-property for the `panoramaOptions`

Furthermore you must remove the parentheses from this line:

```
window.onload = initialize_StreetMap();
```

...otherwise the function will be executed immediately, and not onload.

```js
function initialize_StreetMap() {
  var streetViewLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(52.39648,-4.071235),
      panoramaOptions = {
                            addressControl: false,
                            navigationControl: true,
                            navigationControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                            },
                            position:streetViewLocation
                        },
      panorama = new google.maps
                    .StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("property_streetview"),   
                                        panoramaOptions);

}

window.onload = initialize_StreetMap;
```

```css
     html, body, #property_streetview {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&.js"></script>
<div id="property_streetview"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thats great thanks for the advice it works well in the run code snippet. its still not working for me, I think I probably either need to see if the google maps API already being called for the plain map is causing a conflict OR I need to add some check in to find if there is a streetview nearby using radius.

Comment: how do you call the initialization of the plain map(basically the maps-API will be available onload, except you load the asynchronous version)? Maybe you overwrite the `onload` somewhere.

Comment: Css Issues ;-) Its part of a much bigger page. When I put your code standalone in a HTML page it worked so I looked for other problems. Thanks for the great help